# Edge detection and tracking of melting sample

Tags: matlab, edge-detection, imagefilter

The general problem is to find recession rate of the melting surface of some material.

I tried to implement built-in edge detection filters to detect the front edge (left side in the images), but since the edge is not clear the filter was detecting also many other edges in the image. Simple maximum search of intensity or any RGB color derivative doesn't work as well.

Currently, my approach is to convert to zero all the colors of the environment around the sample (dark black and blue) and leave only color of the sample. Then, based on derivative and first local maximum, detect the front edge. 
The problem is that I don't know how can I define this blue and dark range of colors to filter out. The brightness of this blue color in front of the image, for example, changes along the video and I'm not able to filter it at all images.

Software: Matlab. Image Processing toolbox included

It's not a problem in code, it's more of a concept and way.

1st and last image of the video:

[image: Input 1]

Successful edge detection (blue line) of last image.

[image: Input 1]

Comment: post what you have done so far

Comment: Could you, for the dumb people like me, show which edge you need to track? You will also get better help if you show, rather than explain, what you have done so far (i.e. post code and output image).

Comment: Please check the edited post and image for the edge location

Comment: Nice question. I took the liberty to edit the post in order to show the second picture and to remove a bit the niceties (not needed on StackOverflow). I hope it's fine with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your images you have three fractions: sample (yellow-red), flame (blue-white) and background (dark), however the sample and the flame overlap in the region where you want to detect the edge. It would be nice to separate the flame from the sample and the obvious approach seems to separate it somehow by color. I played around a bit and here is what I came up with.

First, convert the RGB image to HSV where we have basically only a single color channel (hue).

```
hsv = rgb2hsv(img);
```

The [hue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue) is periodic, but in your case the red-yellow sample unfortunately is close to zero and close to 1.

Shift the border in hue so that the cloud of pixel values in HSV space is not separated.

```
h = hsv(:, :, 1);
h = mod(h + 0.5,1); % shift periodically
s = hsv(:, :, 2);
v = hsv(:, :, 3);
```

Let's visualize it.

```
plot3(h(:), s(:), v(:), '.');
xlabel('hue');
ylabel('saturation');
zlabel('value');
```

[image]

Flame and sample seems to be well separated in hue (and partially also in the saturation - the flames are less saturated than the sample).

Find cluster centers for flame, sample and background by simple thresholding. Background is everything with value < 0.2, while flame and sample have value > 0.2 and flame has hue < 0.3, sample hue > 0.3.

```
T1 = 0.3; % threshold on hue (>T1 is sample)
T2 = 0.2; % threshold on value (<T2 is background)
m = h > T1 & v > T2;
sample = [mean(h(m)), mean(s(m)), mean(v(m))];
m = h < T1 & v > T2;
flame = [mean(h(m)), mean(s(m)), mean(v(m))];
m = v < T2;
background = [mean(h(m)), mean(s(m)), mean(v(m))];
C = [sample; flame; background];
```

Let's look at the mean vectors for sample, flame and background in HSV space.

```
  C = 
  0.55004      0.63657      0.79573
  0.23729      0.50927      0.50652
  0.42501      0.50855     0.085589
```

Now comes the interesting part. Let's express the image pixel-wise as a linear combination of these three elements.

```
Y = [h(:), s(:), v(:)];
x = max(Y / C, 0);
x = reshape(x, size(img));
```

It would be nicer if we could enforce smoothness of sample, flame and background as well as non-negativity here, but I could not achieve it within a reasonable amount of time and leave it as exercise.

Let's visualize it.

```
figure;
labels = {'sample', 'flame', 'background'};
for i = 1 : 3
    subplot(1,3,i);
    imagesc(x(:, :, i));
    axis image;
    title(labels{i});
end
colormap(gray);
```

[image]

The overlapping sample and flame were separated (but need some smoothing before further processing). There are some JPEG compression artifacts visible, which will reduce accuracy of the results somewhat. Let's find edges of the separated sample.

```
sample = imgaussfilt(x(:, :, 1), 3);
e = bwareafilt(edge(sample), 1);
```

Here, additionally only the longest edge has been kept. One could also use the flame area as indicator of the front edge.

Let's visualize the original image together with the detected edge.

```
figure;
[x, y] = ind2sub(size(e), find(e));
imshow(img);
hold on;
plot(y, x, 'g.', 'MarkerSize', 2);
```

[image]

Which looks reasonable.

The last frame of the video works equally well. I got a good result without further adapting parameters although that can help.

[image]

As a summary:

Flame and sample were separated by color (hue), then a generic edge detection was applied on the separated sample. The flame can be used as indication of the interesting area for the front edge. There are some internal parameters in the separation (thresholds) as well as in the edge detection (smoothing, threshold) that need to be tweaked.

Comment: Very nice! One thing I’d add for OP: the separated components show strong artifact due to JPEG compression of the image. Color tends to be lost more heavily, we notice that when computing with color. I hope it’s just for posting here that JPEG was used. If not, try to disable lossy compression in your system, you’ll get better results out of this process if you do.

Comment: Hi @Trilarion, I will study your approach and try to implement it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for clarification @CrisLuengo, basically, I read the mp4 video directly in matlab and and then work with the frames. Does this process causes a loss of colors that you talk about?

Comment: @AlexZ: Yes, MP4 is the video equivalent of JPEG. You get the same sort of artifacts. But the method seems to work in spite of those. Just something to pay attention to.

Comment: @Trilarion,
1. How did you recognize the the region of flame, background and the sample on the plot?
2. Why and based on what did you shift the border in hue by 0.5?

Comment: @AlexZ Background is dark (low V value of HSV), sample is yellow-red (specific H value) and flame is white-blue (different H value). Then I just looked at the point cloud and did the assignment by eye. I shifted the hue so that the point cloud is not distributed close to 0 and close to 1 as it was in the beginning without the shift (not shown but easily reproducible). Again by eye I looked at the point cloud and estimated that a shift by 0.5 should be fine.

Comment: @AlexZ Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue (red is at hue 0 and 360 (corresponds to 1 in Matlab)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can obtain reasonably repeatable results by binarizing the red component of the image.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Yves Daoust, I tried to use this approach, but found it impossible to define a unique intensity level threshold to binarize the image, especially it influences the boundary between the flame and the sample.